# Adding Chipmunk Files to XCode NSObjCRuntime NSZone Parse Issue

Tags: parsing, chipmunk

Im working on SpaceViking project from Ray Wenderlich's Cocos2D Book and the project has worked fine so far.  Near the end we are told to add Chipmunk files to the Xcode project and compile & run to test everything is fine without adding any new code yet.

As soon as I do that I get many Parse Issue errors coming from NSZone, NSObject and NSObjCRuntime which I don't get otherwise.

Can anyone help me out on this one?  It should be an error on some of the added files.  How do I find which one and where the error is being generated so I can fix it?

Comment: I guess this is the same problem I met, here is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13234930/919086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check and make sure the added files are 'typed' correctly by Xcode. Make sure they are set to Objective-C, C++ or C (whatever is appropriate in this case). I used to get tons of errors when importing C files that were mistakenly recognized as Objective-C by Xcode. Just changing the file type would solve most of the compile errors. Just and idea.

Comment: How do I change the file types in Xcode and how do I see what file type Xcode has labelled them?

Comment: In Xcode 4 you can click on the file and the details should show in the File Inspector on the right. All the way at the top you should have a drop-down list that allows you to set the file type. In Xcode 3 (if I remember well) you can right click a file, select 'Get Info' and be presented with a similar drop down list in that screen.