# Added CoreData to an old project and compile fails with Parse Issues in CoreData headers

Tags: ios, core-data, compiler-errors

I recently cleaned up an old iOS project and I want to add CoreData. I last worked on this project when iOS 4 was still new.

I am using a bit of boiler plate code I use for another project. This code creates a singleton from which I can access my PersistentStoreCoordinator.

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface CoreDataManager : NSObject {
    ....
}
```

I added my files to my project, added the framework and linked to CoreData.framework in my target.

My project compilation now fails on NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.h, NSPersistentStore.h, NSAtomicStore.h with

- Parse Issue Expected ';' after method prototype
- Parse Issue Expected an Object-ve-C directive after '@'

I am fairly sure it is not my CoreData code since I use the files in another project with no issues.

Comment: I widened my search and looked for anyone having compile errors with iOS frameworks. I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857765/ios-parse-issues-in-nsobjcruntime-nszone-and-nsobject so I took a look at my other project's .pch file and found #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>. I looked at mine old project and sure enough it wasn't there. Ok. I still don't understand this. Why didn't Xcode update the .pch for me?

Comment: Xcode doesn't update the pch. If you added the framework, it shouldn't be necessary to put it there if you also import it wherever you use Core Data classes.