# compiler errors implementing Syphon frame-sharing framework, c++

Tags: c++, server, syphon

I have written some camera capture code in c++ and have bound the image to a texture. I am trying to figure out how to incorporate a syphon server. My c++ code works fine. When I import the syphon framework via Syphon/Syphon.h, I get a zillion

```
Expected unqualified-id
```

and

```
Unknown type name...
```

errors related to NSObjCRuntime.h, NSZone.h, NSObject.h.

I am using x-code on OSX 10.10.5.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

In the build settings -> Custom Compiler Flags, set the "Other C Flags" to "-x objective-c" and set the "Other C++ Flags" to "-x objective-c++"

via:

Bastien

[ios - Parse Issues in NSObjCRuntime, NSZone, and NSObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857765/ios-parse-issues-in-nsobjcruntime-nszone-and-nsobject)